# "Loss" around the transmitting window of a laser cavity due to diffraction?

Tags: optics, waves, laser, diffraction, laser-cavity

Take a laser cavity consisting of a gain medium, a totally reflecting mirror, and a partially transmitting window:

[image]
(*https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Laser-cavity-composed-of-a-gain-medium-in-between-the-two-wavelength-coated_fig8_278637278*)

I read that there is some "loss" around the transmitting window due to **[diffraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffraction)**. But there is no aperture at this transmitting window, and the laser cavity is closed/sealed, so how exactly does this so-called "loss" due to diffraction work?

Comment: The exit window is of finite size - it is an aperture all by itself.

Comment: @JonCuster Ohh, I see. But doesn't diffraction require that the aperture be smaller than the size of the wave itself? Surely the windows are not on the order of the wavelengths of the laser light?

Comment: What is the spatial width of the Gaussian mode of the laser beam in the cavity when it gets to the window? Mess up the beam mode and it is no longer the pure beam mode.

Comment: @JonCuster I'm not completely sure what you mean here, but the spatial widths of the Gaussian modes are on the order of nanometers, are they not? But the windows are much larger, right? So how is the condition for diffraction to occur satisfied at the transmitting mirror?

Comment: So the minimum beam waist of your mode in the laser cavity is on the order of nanometers? Seems quite unlikely...

Comment: @JonCuster Ohh, "beam waist"; I thought you were referring to the laser "modes", such as this https://www.researchgate.net/figure/A-schematic-of-the-longitudinal-mode-structure-in-a-laser-a-The-gain-medium-of-the_fig10_323471526 , and things like FWHM. Ok, I think I understand what you mean.

Comment: Well, those are 'modes' as well, just cavity modes - overloaded term...